# SQl Full-text search doesn't work?

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

When i execute the following sql, nothing happens:

```
select * from docs
where freetext(*, 'my search string')
```

I know that "my search string" is in a field in a table.

The table docs is added to my catalog. The field to search in contains html content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your catalog is up-to-date. Full Text catalogs have to be updated, either with an incremental update or a full population. SQL Server 2005 also has automatically updating catalogs, but they are not set to this by default and these have serious performance implications.

Comment: I am using sql server 2008 express. And how do I update the catalog?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189801.aspx. Have a look at 'start_full' and 'start_incremental'

Comment: Thnx,  I think trhat did the trick, but I can still search on HTML tags. This may not be possible. How do I make sure that html tags cannot be found?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...do you want to make sure that the data can't contain HTML? That's better done on the code side when the data is inserted/updated.

Comment: A html document is stored in my database field. So when I search on 'html' this may not result in a match, since this is a html tag. When I search on 'abc def ghi' this may be found, because this ain't html.

Comment: Are you saying "may not" because you've seen that it doesn't? The engine shouldn't be doing any HTML specific filtering.

Comment: When I search on 'html' I have a match. This may not be possible. I know this is the html tag, because in my (plain) document I don't have the word 'html'. PS: Sorry for my bad English

Comment: So you're saying that you want to exclude HTML tags from your search? If that's the case then, unfortunately, that isn't really possible.

Comment: Yes that's what I am saying. But if that isn't possible, than what is the IFilter for? I read something about it, but don't know much about it..

Comment: The IFilter interface is used by the Windows Indexing Service (which is what's used by SQL Server 2005 for full-text indexing, but NOT for 2008). I don't think that you can use this in SQL Server's full-text indexing, which only exposes a subset of this functionality.

If you wouldn't mind, if this has solved your issue please remember to mark it as the answer :)

Comment: Done :) I have alreadey added a table to my catalog. Now I want another column of the same table added to the catalog. How do I do this?

Comment: You should just be able to select the other column in the same way that you selected the first.

Comment: I've done everything by commands / stored procedures. I don't know how to do it else..

Answer (score 1):

Have you enabled your database tables/columns for full text search?

See example in [Article on freetect including examples on how to enable full text search](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2006/12/06/sql-server-full-text-search-protips-part-2-contains-vs-freetext/)

Comment: I used this: EXEC sp_fulltext_database 'enable'